# Выполнить sudo-рекурсивный chmod

Tags: python, python-2.x, shell, sudo, chmod

Пытаюсь выполнить рекурсивную раздачу прав для всех пользователей для директории ***/myFolder/path***:

```
big_chmod = 'sudo chmod -R 777 /myFolder/path'
print subprocess.Popen(big_chmod, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
```

Получаю ошибку:

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Пожалуйста, подскажите, почему данная команда не работает, и каким наилучшим образом её можно выполнить из кода на **Python**?

Comment: А если руками с консоли запускать sudo пароль случайно не спрашивает ? как минимум вам надо что бы она его не спрашивала. http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%B2_ubuntu

Comment: @Mike, а мне вот думается, что можно осуществить и ввод пароля как-то (через аргументы popen, или ещё каким классным способом). Потому что плохо, если sudo пароль не спрашивает!

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не портить безопасность системы, можно использовать `stdin=PIPE`, скрипт спросит пароль, вы его интерактивно введете.

```
big_chmod = 'sudo chmod -R 777 /myFolder/path'
print subprocess.Popen(big_chmod, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
```

Разумеется, это лишь частный случай для кусочка вашего кода.

**UPD**

Если вам необходима автоматизация, предлагаю такой *НЕБЕЗОПАСНЫЙ* способ:

```
big_chmod = 'sudo chmod -R 777 /myFolder/path'
password = 'PASSWORD'
p = Popen(['sudo', '-S'] + big_chmod, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,
      universal_newlines=True)
sudo_prompt = p.communicate(password + '\n')
```

Однако, я бы вам посоветовал не начинать идти по этому скользкому пути, а, например, настроить права доступа для вашего конкретного пользователя и его конкретных действий в [sudoers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)).

Comment: спасибо за предложенное решение! Однако, интерактивный ввод пароля не подойдёт. Всё должно быть автоматизировано.

Comment: @neo обновил ответ